# rc.sysinit replacement for systemd for early action

Tags: centos, rhel, systemd

With rhel6 / centos6 I used to set some very early actions (like changing default CPU affinity settings) in rc.sysinit early steps.

Now with rhel7/centos7 and systemd, what would be the right way for doing so? 
I was thinking about adding some dedicated service constraint in early target like local-fs-pre.target.

Any comments about this will be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You would add a new `.service` file to `/etc/systemd/system`.  `ExecStart=` would contain your action, while `Before=` `After=`, `Requires=` would help specify another service or target name related to when you wanted the action to run during boot.

### References

- [man systemd.unit](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html)
- [man systemd.service](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html)

Comment: Yes, this is what I meant by "adding some dedicated service constraint to ... ", I should have written "adding some dedicated service as a constraint to ... ". thanks.

Comment: if u want to write something for local-fs-pre, i think u will need `DefaultDependencies=no` otherwise i think you will have an ordering cycle/contradiction